# All tests did not finish - xcode 4.5

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios-simulator, xcode4.5

When i try to run the unit test for my projects, i get test succeeded. But in the log navigator i get warning saying 'All tests did not finish'. But the same code works fine in another machine and all tests succeeds without any warning. I searched for other posts related this and tried everything, but nothing works for me. And also all of a sudden some unit-tests fail without any reason, but succeeds when i run it again. I even tried resetting the simulator, nothing works.

Any suggestions?

Comment: And one more thing i noticed is i could see the tests succeeding in the xcode console, but somehow those test cases are not being written in to the test results log file. And i am not sure whether it is a timing issue.

Comment: I am seeing the same thing.  I have built 9 tests, 8 which pass and 1 which fails (on purpose).  All tests show as being completed in the console, but only four are showing in the Log Navigator.

Comment: look into the build log/run log and see if there's a reason for that (not inwarnings/errors tab! build log!)

Answer (score 5):

Try this... open a Terminal in your project's folder and type the following:

```
xcodebuild -list
```

If you have Unit Tests in your project you should see at least two targets: ProjectName and ProjectNameTests.

Now type the following command (note: you will need quotes around the ProjectNameTests if it has spaces):

```
xcodebuild -target ProjectNameTests build
```

You will almost certainly see something like the following towards the end of the output:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools/RunUnitTests:68: note: RunUnitTests exited without running tests because TEST_AFTER_BUILD was set to NO.
```

You can fix this in Xcode by selecting your project in the Project Navigator (Cmd-1), selecting your ProjectNameTests target, selecting Build Settings and scrolling down to the Unit Testing section. Change the Test After Build setting from No to Yes and type Cmd-U to run your Unit Tests again. This time it should work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: your solution works in my mac but does not work in another mac for the same project.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you get this warning if you are using OCMOCK and you try to mock 'self'. Once i changed this, it fixed my problem.